# How to force Windows 7 to update the DLNA shares?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dlna

I am using my Windows 7 to share content via DLNA to my Google-TV. Frequently it doesn't update what it is sharing. At first I thought it was a codec problem, but then the media appeared a couple days later. The client has an update, and it sees deletions immediately, but still frequently doesn't find new files. Usually rebooting seems to work, but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Luke's answer on a different question](https://superuser.com/a/394806/1551) suggested that running Windows Media Player may cause the update to happen quicker. I don't usually run it, and running it this time resulted in everything updating. So this may in fact work.

Answer (score 1):

Fast and usually working method to refresh the database is simply to restart Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service in batch file (.bat):

net stop WMPNetworkSvc

net start WMPNetworkSvc

pause

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you elaborate on this? *Why* do you say 'usually working'? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made slightly updated batch for windows 7 (original was here:  https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/windows-media-player-12-not-updating-library-370225/)

This is for 64-bit windows, if you have 32-bit change the "rem" prefix accordingly.

```
c:

net stop WMPNetworkSvc

cd %userprofile%\appdata\local\microsoft\media player

del *.wmdb

rem cd e:\program files\windows media player

net start WMPNetworkSvc

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /prefetch:1

rem "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /prefetch:1

echo Done

pause
```

In my case it was not needed to run this batch every time when i try to stream videos to dlna devices, maybe once in two weeks or once in month.